# Error DEP0500 : The folder "<ProjectFolder>\bin\x86\Debug\AppX" could not be deleted.

Tags: visual-studio-2015

`Error DEP0500 : The folder "<ProjectFolder>\bin\x86\Debug\AppX" could not be deleted.`

`Access to the path '<AssemblyName>.dll' is denied.`

I am getting this error with **Visual Studio 2015 Update 2** (just released) and never with the previous **Update 1** or previous versions from VS 2015 downwards.

The problem is that VS 2015 locks a file under the bin folder and this stops a new deployment on a Local Machine. The only workaround is exiting Visual Studio and deleting the bin folder. This happens in about 4 out of 10 deployments and is getting annoying.

Does any body know what causes this?

I have gone through suggested solutions from years back (this problem existed for VS2012 and VS2013) but nothing seems to work. As VS2015 Update 2 is a new release and I had no problem of this sort with the preceding versions, I am hoping that someone with an inside knowledge of Visual Studio could easily pinpoint what new feature(s) of Update 2 is responsible for such annoying deployment error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared after a while with no clue as to what caused it in the first place. No change in hardware or software configuration following Visual Studio with Update 2 as the last installation (on a new i7-6700HQ with 16 GB machine with fresh installation of Windows 10 Enterprise Build 10586 and up-to-date drivers, and OS on 256GB NVe SSD).

I know this is not an answer at all, but thought I should update the readers with the current status. Better than a question without any answer.

Please don't treat this as answer, rather a status update for readers benefit and couldn't find a better place to put this update. Thank you.